# Shifting black disc in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

```
\document[12pt, a4size]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
          \node [or port] (G) at (0,-9) {};
          \node at (G.left) [ocirc,fill=black] {}; 
          \node[left] at (G.in 1) {\(a_1\)};
          \node[left] at (G.in 2) {\(a_2\)};
          \node[right] at (G.out) {\(a_1'+ a_2\)};
          \node[right] at ($(G.out) + (3, 0)$) {\textbf{subjunction-Gate} (symbolises $x_1'+ x_2$);};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following image.
[image]
But I want the black disc in the position where `a_1` meets the gate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuitikz [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) on page 124 has some diagrams about the gate anchors:

[image]

From here you can find that you need `.bin 1` for the position of the circle.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4size]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{circuitikz}
          \node [or port] (G) at (0,-9) {};
          \node at (G.bin 1) [ocirc,fill=black] {}; 
          \node[left] at (G.in 1) {\(a_1\)};
          \node[left] at (G.in 2) {\(a_2\)};
          \node[right] at (G.out) {\(a_1'+ a_2\)};
          \node[right] at ($(G.out) + (3, 0)$) {\textbf{subjunction-Gate} (symbolises $x_1'+ x_2$);};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks for the comment, the manual I quoted is from 2021/04/20, but the code itself was compiled with a slightly older `circuitikz`. If this code does not work in the latest version then maybe you can add an answer with the necessary changes?

Comment: The differences had to do with the page numbers mostly.  If there is a 2021/04/20 version, I need to update my packages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo the April 20 manual is the one currently on CTAN.

Comment: I (almost) always update my packages on Friday anyway.